# Disable pdf toolbar while displaying pdf in an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, safari

Currently we are displaying PDF document in an iframe. By using preferences we can disable the top toolbar of PDF .But we can not force clients to do that. I am looking for a solution where i can programmatically disable PDF toolbar in an iframe on safari browsers.

I tried setting toolbar=0 for iframe tag but it dint work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. In general you cannot "force" clients to do anything - first, because they ultimately control how the data you send them will be interpreted or displayed, and second because you actually have no idea what plugin, if any, they use for viewing PDF files in the browser. If someone has all their PDF plugins disabled, their browser will automatically download the file anyway.

What exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: when we open a PDF document in an iframe,it displays PDF with toolbar on its top and left. (PDF reader plugin : like adobe reader /Foxit reader plugin's toolbar). I want to disable the top toolbar.